# Spurious display of frame-time statistics on some applications

Tags: linux, video, opengl, mesa

Since I cannot precisely tell what upgrade (possibly `nvidia-drivers` from 340 to 470 or mesa 20 to 22 or even xorg-server 1.20 to 21) or following the first time I ran `glxgears` after upgrading ? :
I (not systematically though) can see, superposed on the upper left corner of the window of applications such as *vlc* or *chromium*, some report very similar to the one I would get running *glxgears* as one can see below on some screen capture of vlc upper-left window corner :

[image]

Is this a bug ? a misconfiguration problem ? a feature ? Whatever : How can I just get rid of this ?

---

**EDIT 1 :** Would that be the *[Graphics API Visual Indicator](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/470.161.03/README/openglenvvariables.html)* ?
I'd be surprised since its display is not systematic and I made sure the `__GL_SHOW_GRAPHICS_OSD` environment variable is not set.

---

BTW : Running a KDE-Plasma desktop, I know it offers the possibility to display informations regarding the frame rate but I do not think this very question related since this option is not set and the display of this information is radically different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some setting I had not noticed accessible via the *nvidia X server settings utility*

(`X Screen 0 > OpenGL Settings > Enable Graphics API Visual Indicator`)

Seems to command to that display irrespective of the `__GL_SHOW_GRAPHICS_OSD` environment variable value.

A post 340 nvidia-drivers novelty I had not noticed.